# Mysql unable to get aggregate query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with values as follows(MySql):

```
SQL> SELECT deptno, ename FROM emp ORDER BY deptno, ename;

DEPTNO ENAME
------ ----------
    10 CLARK
    10 KING
    10 MILLER
    20 ADAMS
    20 FORD
    20 JONES
    20 SCOTT
    20 SMITH
    30 ALLEN
    30 BLAKE
    30 JAMES
    30 MARTIN
    30 TURNER
    30 WARD

14 rows selected.
```

but I need them in the following less convenient format:

```
DEPTNO ENAME
------ -----------------------------------------
    10 CLARK, KING, MILLER
    20 ADAMS, FORD, JONES, SCOTT, SMITH
    30 ALLEN, BLAKE, JAMES, MARTIN, TURNER, WARD
```

Kindly help me to achiever above result/output.

Comment: [`GROUP_CONCAT(expr)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT deptno, group_concat(ename order by ename) as ename
FROM emp 
group by deptno
ORDER BY deptno;
```